# For those who don't believe baptism is required for salvation, when, scripturally, does someone die with Christ?

Tags: biblical-basis, soteriology, baptism, death, creeds-and-confessions

Paul recites as part of an early creed.

> 2 Timothy 2:11 **...If we have died with him, we will also live with him;...**

Here it seems that our living with Christ is conditioned on us having **died with Christ.** The only place in the scriptures where we are described as **uniting ourselves with Christ's death,** *I am aware of*, is through baptism:

> Romans 6:3-5 3 Do you not know that **all of us who have been baptized into Christ Jesus were baptized into his death?** 4 **We were buried therefore with him by baptism into death,** in order that, just as Christ was raised from the dead by the glory of the Father, we too might walk in newness of life.
> 5 **For if we have been united with him in a death like his, we shall certainly be united with him in a resurrection like his.**

(*See also Colossians 2:12 and surrounding verses)

(I've significantly edited my question for greater clarity based on responses below)

For those who do not believe in baptism for salvation please answer specifically the following questions:

1. Do you believe it is necessary to **have died and been buried** with Christ in order to be saved? If not please provide a biblical basis for why not.
2. Do you believe that **we are not buried with Christ** at baptism?
   If not, what is the biblical basis for believing that we are not **united with Christ's death** at baptism?
3. If you believe that **we died with Christ** at belief (or at some other time), what is the biblical basis for claiming that our **moment of death with Christ** is the moment we first believed in Jesus Christ specifically or some other specific moment?

Comment: John the Baptist has clearly explained this Mark ch 1  "I baptize you with water, but he will baptize you with the Holy Spirit."

Answer (score 5):

**Summary**

For those Christians, the union with Christ's death happened when we trusted in Christ to *apply* personally Jesus's historic death on the cross *through faith*, which happened **prior** to the public act of baptism.  Being united with Christ's death through faith is *necessary* but baptism is *optional* (although recommended), being a later, outward expression of the inward reality of faith.  Faith is the **instrument** (the application) while baptism is the later **symbol** (the signification) of our death with Christ.

**Support of the above, from John Piper**

For exegesis of the Roman 6:3-5 and the Col 2:12 you quoted to support the above interpretation, I refer you to 2 sermons of John Piper, pastor of Bethlehem Baptist Church:

- [United with Christ in Death and Life, Part 2](https://www.desiringgod.org/messages/united-with-christ-in-death-and-life-part-2) where he helpfully distinguished 3 events *chronologically* in a Christian's life and gave 3 reasons for interpreting the baptism in Rom 6:3-5 as *symbol*, not *instrument* of dying with Christ:

  > 1. First, there is the historical event of Christ's death at Calvary when God saw us in Christ, so that his death was our death.  This was the *accomplishment* of our death with Christ.
  > 2. Second, we trusted in Christ and were thus united to him experientially, so our death with him became personal to us.  This was the *application* to us through faith of what God accomplished for us at Calvary.
  > 3. Third, we were baptized in Christ's name.  This was the *signification* of our death with Christ.
  >
  > So there was the historical *accomplishment* of our death with Christ at Calvary, then the experiential *application* of our death with Christ by faith, then the symbolic *signification* of our death with Christ by baptism. *Accomplishment* in history, *application* by faith, *signification* through baptism.

  John Piper admitted that others disagree with saying that baptism in Rom 6:3-4 "signifies" our death with Christ.  The others say instead that baptism *effects* or *causes* or *brings about* our death with Christ, stressing the words "through baptism" to mean not the *symbol* of our death with Christ, but the *instrument* of our death with Christ.

  He then gave 3 reasons to interpret this text with the "signifies" option:

  1. > The overwhelming teaching of this letter and the rest of the New Testament is that we are justified by faith alone because of the union with Christ that happens through faith. ...
  2. > When Paul explicitly relates faith and baptism he does so in a way that shows faith is the instrument that unites us to Christ, not physical baptism. For example, Galatians 3:26 –27: "You are all sons of God *through faith* in Christ Jesus. For all of you who were baptized into Christ have clothed yourselves with Christ." The "for" at the beginning of verse 27 shows that "baptism into Christ" is either an outward expression of faith or a proof of faith. But it is "*through faith*" that we are sons of God. ...
  3. > ... I do not think it stretches the words beyond ordinary use to say that Romans 6:3-4 describes the *symbol* of dying with Christ rather than the *instrument* of dying with Christ. ... Now here's the analogy I would suggest to show that this language can be the language of symbol, not instrument: "All of us who have put on the ring of marriage have, by putting on this ring, forsaken all others to cleave only to our wives. Therefore by this ring I am united to my wife alone and dead to all others." ...  I would mean that putting on the ring is a sign of my forsaking all others and cleaving only to her. The decisive leaving and cleaving is in the promise, the covenant, the vows. "I plight thee my troth." "I promise you my faithfulness." Then comes the ring, the symbol. ...   In that analogy, the vows stand for faith in Christ, and the ring stands for baptism. And the point is that we often talk this way. We often speak of the symbol as though it brings about what it only signifies.
- [Is Baptism Necessary for Salvation?](https://www.desiringgod.org/interviews/is-baptism-necessary-for-salvation) he brought other scriptural support for faith being the sole instrument of justification, making baptism an outward expression of faith **after** the decisive faith act that unites us to Christ.  Here's what I think John Piper would answer your 3 sub-questions based on this sermon, which represents Bible interpretation from the Reformed Baptist tradition:

  1. **Do you believe it is necessary to have died and been buried with Christ in order to be saved?** Yes.
  2. **Do you believe that we are not buried with Christ at baptism?**  No, not at baptism but at faith.

     - [Col 2:11-12](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Colossians%202%3A11-12&version=ESV) brought the image of circumcision as analogy of baptism but [Rom 4:11](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=rom+4%3A11&version=ESV) says Abraham "received the sign of circumcision as a seal of the righteousness that he had by faith while he was still uncircumcised", so John Piper said:

       > this text would say that baptism is a sign of a righteousness that we have *before* we are baptized, because we have it through faith and through union with Christ.
     - He also highlight "calling on his name" in [Acts 22:16](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=acts+22%3A16&version=ESV) ("Rise and be baptized and wash away your sins, *calling on his name*") and said:

       > Baptism is the outward expression of calling on the name of the Lord in faith. It’s not the water that effects our justification or union with Christ. The water is a picture of the cleansing, but the faith in the heart, the call on the Lord from faith, is what unites us and forgives us.
     - Similarly he highlight the *appeal* in [1 Pet 3:21](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+pet+3%3A21&version=ESV) ("Baptism, which corresponds to this, now saves you, not as a removal of dirt from the body but as an *appeal* to God for a good conscience, through the resurrection of Jesus Christ") to have the same function as the *call* in Acts 22:16.  John Piper said:

       > In other words, it’s the call of faith from the heart, not the water. Peter explicitly says, “not as a removal of dirt from the body.” In other words, it’s not the actual functioning of the water that does the saving. Even though he just said baptism saves you, what he means is that this outward act signifies an appeal to God that’s coming from the heart. It’s that faith that saves.
  3. **If you believe that we died with Christ at belief (or at some other time), what is the biblical basis for claiming that our moment of death with Christ is the moment we first believed in Jesus Christ specifically or some other specific moment?** Buried with Christ happens at *justification* (Note: [justification is by faith alone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sola_fide), a key Reformation doctrine, something John Piper obviously subscribes to).  John Piper then cited Scriptural support for justification by faith: Rom 3:28, Rom 5:1, Rom 4:5, John 3:16, Acts 13:38-39, etc.

Comment: Thank you, @gratefuldisciple for that response. My question is where do the scriptures say we die with Christ. If it is not exclusively at baptism, is there scripture that states or means that we die with Christ at the moment of faith?

Comment: @Austin Gal 2:20, part of the argument of why we are saved by faith not by keeping the "law".  I recommend reading [Part 1](https://www.desiringgod.org/messages/united-with-christ-in-death-and-life-part-1) of the exegesis of Rom 6:1-7 as well.

Comment: @Austin Personally, after dabbling in theology & philosophy for many years, I am convinced that there are **more than one responsible** interpretation of the Bible on "secondary" theoretical matters such as when exactly our union with Christ's death happened (the "primary" being the doctrine of Trinity, etc.).  I respect John Piper who chose one option, showed **responsible** exegesis to support it, and acknowledged that this is a point of controversy. Personally I believe baptism does more than what John Piper says, but I highly respect his scholarship to represent certain Reformed tradition.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification.

Comment: @Austin I added scriptural support John Piper used to answer your 3 sub-questions.

Comment: Thanks again for your feedback and for answering the specific questions. +1

Comment: Thanks that excellent. Plus Rom 10:9 “if thou shalt confess with thy mouth the Lord Jesus, and shalt believe in thine heart that God hath raised him from the dead, thou shalt be saved” Could make a case for uttering/admitting “christ is lord” beyond just that verse. Im remembering all this again is all. And I kept thinking there was something else I was forgetting.  Thanks for all answers Grateful D 

Answer (score 5):

One is already unified with Jesus Christ before they are water baptized. Look at Acts 10:44-48.

The Apostle Peter was still speaking these words, the Holy Spirit fell upon all those who were listening to the message.Vs45, "And all the circumcised believers who had come with Peter were amazed, because (or why?) the gift of the Holy Spirit had been poured out upon the Gentiles also.

Vs46, "For they were hearing them speaking with tongues and exalting God, then Peter answered, Vs47, "Surely no one can refuse the water for these to be baptized who have RECEIVED THE HOLY SPIRIT just as we did, can he?"

Vs48, "And he ordered them to be baptized in the name of Jesus Christ. Then they asked him to stay on for a few days."

You have here a "model" where the Gentiles received the gift of the Holy Spirit "BEFORE" they were water baptized. Notice 1 Peter 3:21, "And corresponding to that baptism now saves you--not the removal of the dirt from the flesh, but an appeal to God FOR A GOOD CONSCIENCE--through the resurrection of Jesus Christ."

It takes more than washing in water ("the putting away of the filth of the flesh") to cleanse from sin. This means it is not the water itself that saves, but Christ, who is symbolized by the ark. Cleansing comes by the shed blood of the Son of God. God looks beyond the act of baptism and searches to see whether the believer has truly repented and dedicated his life to divine service.

Lastly, the thief on the cross ask Jesus to remember him when He gets to His kingdom. The Lord said, "this day you shall be with Me in Paradise." The point is the fact that he did not get water baptized but Jesus knew the man's heart and he repented thereby qualifying him to be with Jesus.

Comment: Mr Bond, you seem to be discussing union with Christ and salvation in general. This could be a general response to a question on baptism. My question is what biblical-basis does one have that they specifically died with Christ without being baptized and when does it happen. Does the bible specifically tie dying with Christ to initial belief the way it ties it to baptism?

Comment: So Mr Bond, I edited my question for clarity. Please let me know if that helps.

Comment: @Austin Said, "when, scripturally, does someone die with Christ." We die with Christ the when we are born again/saved. Ephesians 2:4-7, "But God, being rich in mercy, because of His great love with which He loved us, even when we were dead in transgressions, made us ALIVE together with Christ (by grace you have been saved) and raised us up with Him, and seated us with Him in the heavenly places, in Christ Jesus, in order that in the ages to come He might show the surpassing riches of His grace in kindness toward us in Christ Jesus." When your saved your automatically seated with Jesus Christ.

Comment: @Austin While your title asked that question, the body of said question  contains a scripture quotation that you use to argue that being united in Christ's death happens at baptism, and question 2 asks people to explain why said death cannot occur at baptism. Seeing as being united in Christ's death is a requirement for salvation, and the criminal on the cross was saved but not baptized, that is an argument that baptism is not when "dying with Christ" occurs.

Comment: Mr.Bond & @trlkly I wanted to address this one issue. **We don't actually know** whether or not the Theif on the Cross was baptized under Christ and the Bible supports conjecture that he may have been. 1st, Mk 1:5 says (hyperbolically) that all of Judea was going to be baptized by John. In Jn 3:26, John's disciples complained everyone was getting baptized by Jesus and even the Pharisees were aware of the situation (4:1-2). So with all the people getting baptized and the thief on the cross's noteworthy prior knowledge and faith in Christ's kingdom it's quite possible he was a baptized disciple.

Comment: So Mr. Bond, I wanted to compliment you on your previous comment, I did not think of using Eph 2:4-7 that way. I would like it if you incorporate it into your answer and respond to my specific subquestions that I may upvote it in addition to your comment.

Comment: @Austin Your welcome Austin. I was just going to respond to the idea that the thief on the cross could have been baptized. No way! Your still "assuming" that being water baptized means your saved. I gave you a model at Acts 10 where they received the Holy Spirit "BEFORE" Cornelius was water baptized. How do you explain that? The Scriptures are "orderly" and do not contradict themselves. The Scriptures are also "logical" because God is "NOT" illogical and He is not "capricious." Study your Bible with diligence, do your homework. Look up words, read what Scholars say to help you understand.

Comment: Just wanted to add... the thief on the cross *literally* died with Christ :), so perhaps he doesn't make for a good example if we're calling baptism a symbolic but required "**burial with Christ**". That said, I believe this is all very legalistic. It is God's heart that *none should perish* - yet we argue that Christ's death was insufficient... we must also gather enough hydrogen dioxide to submerge our dying flesh into. Is a person who comes to the knowledge of the Truth in the middle of the desert precluded from salvation?

Comment: *If you confess with your tongue that Jesus is Lord, and believe in your heart that God raised Him from the dead, you will be saved.* For many, baptism is their first public proclamation. This is important. Perhaps for some, it's an act that takes them from "someone who has heard the gospel" to "someone who has made the choice".

Comment: For those that believe baptism a *strict requirement* for salvation... must the water be 100% without impurities? Probably no person has had that type of baptism. Could then the water be muddy? Or... could it be substituted with Coca-Cola?... that has water in it. Or how about milk? Would that be okay? Jello? Or... does God have a strict viscosity requirement for baptism? Perhaps rolling around in moist grass? Or even just humid air should be sufficient? A snowball to the face?

Comment: Mr. Bond, to my scriptural evidence that the Theif may have possibly been baptized you say "no way" without offering proof to refute that possibility. Please forgive me if I don't believe you solely on your words. Not even Jesus asked us to believe what he said just because he said it (John 5:31-36, John 10:38).

Comment: Regarding Cornelius, see the story of the Holy Spirit (HS) and the Murderous King Saul (1 Sam 19:19-20:1). The HS gift of prophesy was given not to save Paul, but to save David. Having the HS come upon you doing miraculous gifts doesn't mean you are saved. Jesus explains you will not enter the kingdom if you call on Christ and do miracles, but not God's will (Mt7:21-23). Thus Peter insisted they be baptized. The HS wasn't sent because Cornelius was saved but to show that Jews should not stand in God's way for the Gentiles (Ac11:17), and so Peter immediately commanded them to be baptized.

Comment: @AaronCicali , If you believe you must believe in Jesus to be saved you also say that Christ death is not sufficient. Christ Death is not sufficient to save any sinner unless that sinner adds to that death his own faith in Christ (John 3:18).  Remember belief is also a work (John 6:28-29).

Comment: @AaronCicali , Read Rom 10:9-10 in context of the entire book. It's addressed to those who already confess the gospel in their mouth and heart (v8), have been baptized (6:3), are called saints (1:7).  This isn't instructions to non-Christians on how to be saved, but to Christians on how to continue being saved. See also 1 Cor 15:1-2, where Paul explains to Christians how to continue being saved by the gospel by holding fast to the gospel. See also how Jesus instructs baptized believers to confess him to be saved (Matt 10:32-33). The Bible only ever tells baptized believers to confess Christ.

Comment: One must believe, but not as a work. *Even the demons believe - and they shudder*. Without belief - what good is any of it? Paul doesn't give a command to baptize in chapter 6. Although he does refer to "*those of us who were baptized*", he tells them to "*not let sin reign in your mortal body so that you obey its evil desires.*"

Comment: @Austin Your "exegetical" skills need polishing. You quoted to me Acts 11::17 as in regards to Cornelius but failed to quote verses 16 & 18. Vs16, "And I remembered the word of the Lord, how He used to say, "John baptized you with water, but you shall be baptized with the HOLY SPIRIT." Vs17, "If God therefore gave to them the same gift as He gave to us also AFTER BELIEVING IN THE LORD JESUS CHRIST, who was I that I could stand in God's way." Notice water baptism is not mentioned. Peter is clearly saying that they received the Holy Spirit and Peter will not get in the way of God for doing so.

Comment: @Mr.Bond, forgive me. I assumed you were familiar with the narrative. Water baptism is commanded in Acts 10:47-48. In Acts 11, Peter is recounting what changed his perspective towards Gentiles (The vision & The Holy Spirit baptism) and not every exact thing already described in chapter 10. So when Peter says "who was I that I could stand in God's way?” it helps explain what he was thinking when he said, "Can anyone withhold water for baptizing these people, who have received the Holy Spirit just as we have?”  Peter and the Jews needed the sign to know it was right to baptize the Gentiles.

Comment: @Austin. Peter and the Jews did receive a "sign" as you put it. At Acts 10:46 they were hearing them speaking in tongues and EXALTING God. THEN or after they saw the sign that they had received the Holy Spirit did Peter command them to get baptized. Read the following to show they believed first and then got baptized. https://biblehub.com/commentaries/acts/10-47.htm Now, can you explain Acts 8:14-18? The Samaritans heard the word of God and were water baptized at Acts 8:16 but did not receive the Holy Spirit, why? And your telling me I'm not familiar with the narrative?

Comment: @Mr.Bond there is no need to take things personally. Never said you were not familiar. I just assumed that you were.  And really there is no need to rely on commentaries to know they believed before being baptized since we can read the scripture itself. So why do you think the Holy Spirit did not fall on the Samaritans until after they believed and after they were baptized but not before the Apostles laid their hands on them? You seem to be the one who thinks it makes some point, so please explain what point you think it makes.

Answer (score 4):

Anyone who says that baptism is required for salvation must therefore be saying that baptism in some way has an *essential effect* for the person's salvation.

Those who say baptism isn't required for salvation generally say that it is *symbolic* of the real salvation effects of the death and resurrection of Christ. (Though many churches teach a Sacramental view, in which God does truly act through the sacraments, even though those acts are distinct from Christ's once-for-all mediatorial work accomplished by his death and resurrection.)

There are multiple views of what it means for us to be United to Christ, but the doctrine is most prominent in Reformed Theology, and in Reformed Theology it is the Holy Spirit who unites us to Christ, in faith. So the Westminster Confession says

> WCF 11.4: God did, from all eternity, decree to justify the elect; and Christ did, in the fullness of time, die for their sins and rise again for their justification; nevertheless *they are not justified until the Holy Spirit doth, in due time, actually apply Christ unto them*.

> WCF 11.1: Those whom God effectually calleth, he also freely justifieth: not by infusing righteousness into them, but by pardoning their sins, and by accounting and accepting their persons as righteous; not for any thing wrought in them, or done by them, but for Christ's sake alone; not by imputing faith itself, the act of believing, or any other evangelical obedience to them, as their righteousness; but *by imputing the obedience and satisfaction of Christ unto them, they receiving and resting on him and his righteousness by faith; which faith they have not of themselves, it is the gift of God*.

Comment: Interesting commentary. Thanks for your response. Not sure what you mean by essential effect. Is faith an essential effect? I believe baptism is required for salvation, but not necessary. God has the ability to waive any one of his requirements. Also, it doesn't seem the answer addresses the main question regarding when is a person united with the death of Jesus according to the scriptures other than by baptism.

Comment: @Austin I don't believe baptism is essential for salvation, and I don't understand any of the arguments for that position. If you want an explanation of the Biblical support for the Spirit uniting us to Christ I'll look at adding that soon.

Comment: Its not obvious to me that a union with Christ means specifically to die with Christ: the condition expressed in 2 Tim 2:12 for living with Christ. I'm interested in when a Christian could have died with Christ according to the scriptures. Also, I don't belief baptism is essential for salvation but it is now required by God for salvation. Kinda like how circumcision was at one point absolutely required by God to be in a covenant relationship with Him, but is clearly not essential since God was able to enter into a covenant with Abraham before he made circumcision a requirement.

Comment: Also, I removed **union-with-christ** tag, since it seemed to be causing confusion with what I was specifically asking. I included the **bible-basis** tag, since this what I mean when seeking a scriptural response, and I included the **creeds-and-confession** tag since my whole question is predicated on an early creed confessed by Paul in 2 Tim 2:12-13.

Comment: @Austin 1) Your Q is clearly about union with Christ, and your Q asks for scriptural support, so both tags should be there.  2) You're not being clear when saying baptism is "required" but not "necessary" / "essential".  Please see my answer, which expands curiousdannii's answer in more detail how baptism is *symbolic* and thus not essential.

Comment: @gratefuldisciple, yes my question is about union with Christ, but people are answering that subject in general instead of the specific question related to dying with Christ, hence confusion.

Comment: @Austin I understand.  But `union-with-christ` is an established theological term to include not just dying but rising and [many other aspects](https://www.crossway.org/articles/10-things-you-should-know-about-union-with-christ/) in our life in Christ.  Also, I made a mistake about the [`biblical-basis`](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biblical-basis) tag.  I agree with @curiousdannii (our esteemed moderator) that the tag usage is for other kinds of questions, see https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3409/what-types-of-questions-can-i-ask-on-this-site .

Comment: @greatfuldisciple, i know that union-with-christ includes many other aspects of our life with Christ. That's why I desired to avoid using that tag, since answerers were tempted to answer the general subject and not the specific question. Regarding biblical-basis, are you saying that prominant denominations like the Baptist don't have biblical basis for believing that they died with Christ upon belief or at some other time?

Comment: @Austin 1) From tag usage guide: Biblical-basis questions are for "how Christians use the Bible to derive a specific belief."  Your Q doesn't assert a specific belief but instead ask for interpretation of a passage for a certain group of Christian.  2) I don't think you have to worry about tag use to influence answers, since they look more for the Q text.  3) In matters of tagging, I **strongly recommend to defer to the moderators** who have been in the site for 7+ years and who had developed the tagging system that makes sense for various groups of Christians to easily find questions, etc.

Comment: @Austin If you disagree about tagging, please raise a Q in the [Meta site](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/), the right place for it.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple, Ok I tried to make the question more clear and aligned with the tags. Is the edit helpful? Thanks again for all your feedback.

Comment: @Austin Yes, the edit *does* clarify your expected answer.

Answer (score 0):

Baptism is the outward recognition of inward spiritual changes that have already occurred.   The Episcopal church recognizes spiritual baptism.

Paul can be hard to figure out, and nowhere as much as in Romans.   You KNOW he was a Jewish rabbi the way he thinks in circles.

To me, to be baptized into Christ's death and resurrection means that to the baptized, one's life is not one's own, and one might be called to risk it or lose it - the Time of Trial.

Clearly that has little to do with the ritual of baptism itself.

However, with all of that said, I'm actually working on Romans at the moment, and, I suspect Paul was talking about a completely different issue.  He meant to die to sin and rise to whatever the bleep he was talking about.  I vaguely recall from my first effort that he went on about that at some length.  New life, or a state of grace, or righteousness, or something that really wasn't because as he points out it's an ongoing process.   The day Paul said anything at all straightforwardly in that Epistle the sun won't rise.  What he thought we were reborn to can vary with what church you go to.

Now, I'm actually working on LUTHER's interpretation of Romans vs other interpretations.  One problem is people intellectually trapped in their time and their traditions.   Luther's tendency to rigid thinking at times wound him around in circles as to what needed to happen in order for what.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259).